Refactoring a selector to prevent re-renders for state DTOs with many properties
My problem is that I have a list that is being passed down to be rendered in another component (The ProcedureParameterList)
Both ProcedureParameterList and ProcedureParamater are Generic components that are used for similar DTO's, and I am not allowed to change them.
The problem with it is:
When I change the text in one Guideline, the whole list renders instead of the affected Guideline.
From dev-tools I see that the ProcedureParameterList rendered because props changed, and if I follow it down I see that the Guideline rendered because the Hook 3 changed
I can't find the hook with number 3, however, if I remove the following line:
  const allGuidelines: GuidelineDTO[] = useSelector(currentGuidelines)

The whole list won't render only the component. I believe that's expected since the currentGuidelines looks at the entire DTO[], that being said it will always re-evaluate when I change the text even if it's not relevant for it.
The relevant code is as follows:
EDIT
export type  GuidelineDTO = {
  text: string
  mainGuideline: number
  other: string
}

export type SomeProps<T extends GuidelineDTO> = {
  index: number
  expanded: boolean
  onExpandedChange: (expanded: boolean) => void
  onTextChange?: (bezeichnung: string) => void
  children?: React.ReactNode
  draggable?: boolean
  process: T
}

export const currentPoolSelector = createSelector(
  [(state: RootState) => state.pool.currentPoolDTO],
  (currentPoolDTO) => currentPoolDTO
)

export const currentGuidelinesSelector = createSelector(
  [currentPoolSelector],
  (pool) => pool.guidelineList
)

export const currentGuidelines = createSelector(
  [currentGuidelinesSelector],
  (guidelineList) => {
    return myfunc(guidelineList.guidelines)
  }
)

const Guideline = memo((props: SomeProps<GuidelineDTO>): JSX.Element =>{
  const {process: guideline} = props
  const allGuidelines: GuidelineDTO[] = useSelector(currentGuidelines)
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

  const [mainGuidelines, setMainGuidelines] = useState<GuidelineDTO[]>()

  useEffect(() => {
    setMainGuidelines(allGuidelines.filter(g => guideline.mainGuideline))
  }, [allGuidelines, guideline.mainGuideline]);

  const mainGuideine: GuidelineDTO = useMemo(
    ()=>     guideline.mainGuideline == null? null : mainGuidelines.filter(g => g.mainGuideline !== guideline.mainGuideline)[0]

    ,[ mainGuidelines, guideline.mainGuideline])


  const handleMainGuidelineChange = useCallback(
    (neuG: Value<GuidelineDTO>): void => {
      const mainGuidelinenumber: number = (neuG as GuidelineDTO)?.mainGuideline
      dispatch(setPoolGuidelineNumber({ guideline, mainGuidelinenumber }))
    },
    [dispatch, guideline]
  )

  const dispatchTextChanged = useCallback(
    (text: string) => {
      dispatch(setpoolGuidelineText({guideline, text }))
    },
    [dispatch, guideline]
  )

  return (
    <>
      <ProcedureParameter
        key={`processparameter${index}-${guideline?.nummer}`}
        onTextChange={dispatchTextChanged}
        {...props}
      >
      {mainGuideineEnabled && (
            <Select
              options={mainGuidelines ?? []}
              onChange={handleMainGuidelineChange}
              clearable
              usePortal
            />
      )}
      </ProcedureParameter>
      </>
  )
})

const GuidelinesList = (): JSX.Element => {
  const guidelinesList= useSelector(currentGuidelinesSelector)


  return (
    <ProcedureParameterList
      key='overview-guidelines'
      context='guidelines'
      procedureParameterList={guidelinesList.guidelines ?? []}
      procedureParameterComponent={Guideline}
    />
  )
}

export default GuidelinesList

I tried to pass in my guideline, thinking that maybe it would realize that nothing relevant for him changed, but It's impossible. Please don't ask me about this code, I have seen it work to other places. A coworker suggested that I can try this, but if I say I understand it, it would be a lie
//selectors.ts
export const currentGuidelineTry= (
  currentGuidline
) => createSelector(
  [currentGuidelines],
  (guidlinesList) => {
    return myfunc(guidelineList.guidelines)
  }
)
//Guideline.tsx
const allGuidelines =  currentGuidelineTry(guideline)
const selectableMainGuidelines = useSelector(
  state => allGuidelines(state)
)

The selector either must go, but then where should I move him and why?
It would be ideal if I could make him track only what's relevant for him instead of looking at everything.
I mean when I change something in Guideline with number 2 why does the
Guideline with number 5 has to know about it.
Any help would be highly appreciated, I have no idea how to refactor or solve something like this
EDIT 2: After a little bit of refactoring, it worked.
  const allGuidelines: GuidelineDTO[] = useSelector(currentGuidelines)

I simply passed down the allGuidelines as prop to a new component, and it stopped rendering the whole list, now it renders only the Guideline component that changed. It's unclear why this worked, but in case someone finds an approach like this useful in the future.
Here is what I did
const Guideline = memo((props: SomeProps<GuidelineDTO>): JSX.Element => {
  const {process: guideline} = props
  const allGuidelines: GuidelineDTO[] = useSelector(currentGuidelines)
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

  return (
    <>
      <ProcedureParameter
        key={`processparameter${index}-${guideline?.nummer}`}
        onTextChange={dispatchTextChanged}
        {...props}
      >
        {mainGuideineEnabled &&
          <MainGuideline allGuidelines={allGuidelines}/>
        }
      </ProcedureParameter>
    </>
  )
})

interface MainGuidelineProps {
  allGuidelines?: GuidelineDTO[]
}

const MainGuideline = memo((props: MainGuidelineProps) => {
  const {allGuidelines} = props
  const [mainGuidelines, setMainGuidelines] = useState<GuidelineDTO[]>()
  useEffect(() => {
    setMainGuidelines(allGuidelines.filter(g => guideline.mainGuideline))
  }, [allGuidelines, guideline.mainGuideline]);

  const mainGuideine: GuidelineDTO = useMemo(
    () => guideline.mainGuideline == null ? null : mainGuidelines.filter(g => g.mainGuideline !== guideline.mainGuideline)[0]

    , [mainGuidelines, guideline.mainGuideline])


  const handleMainGuidelineChange = useCallback(
    (neuG: Value<GuidelineDTO>): void => {
      const mainGuidelinenumber: number = (neuG as GuidelineDTO)?.mainGuideline
      dispatch(setPoolGuidelineNumber({guideline, mainGuidelinenumber}))
    },
    [dispatch, guideline]
  )

  const dispatchTextChanged = useCallback(
    (text: string) => {
      dispatch(setpoolGuidelineText({guideline, text}))
    },
    [dispatch, guideline]
  )
  return (
    <Select
      options={mainGuidelines ?? []}
      onChange={handleMainGuidelineChange}
      clearable
      usePortal
    />
  )
})


Is the problem in currentGuidelinesSortedAscendingSelector or combinedGuidlineSelector, or both selector functions? And what exactly is the issue or problem here? What is being updated and causing selectors to re-compute? Please [edit] to clarify the specific problem you would like help with.

Both of them are problematic.
The text is being updated, which is completely irrelevant at this point for the selectors.
I will edit this tomorrow. Every fixme comment is what I tried to do, but it did not work out. My question is actually how to narrow down the scope of a selector, or have him memoized based on different criteria like the array.length. or ids Or if there is a refactoring pattern in these cases? Some code I managed to put in the state to prevent re-renders, but here it is not possible

Problem is still unclear. Is it that currentGuidelinesSortedAscendingSelector(guideline) creates a new selector each time it's called? The guidelinesSelector is called too often? Is there a re-rendering issue, or the returned guidelinesSelector re-computes too often? "The problem with components in a list rendering too often is mostly caused by props or keys, in my case is the selector" - What components in what list? What props or keys are you referring to?

Hey Drew, thanks for taking the time. I simplified the code a bit and added some more information. I hope now it's easier to understand.
The currentGuidelines is being called too often. The rendering is problematic because for every letter I type I need to render a list of 100 elements.
About the props and keys, I meant in general from other posts in stack overflow where people had a list that was constantly rendering.

Sorry, if anything it's more confusing now that you've added a few more selectors and literally every identifier has the word "guideline" in it, I have no idea which specific unit of code you might be referring to, or if you've an issue in a selector, a component, something else. Can you try paring the problem down to a simpler [mcve] that reproduces the problem you are trying to address?
